# Update table column based on condition of existing and another table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two huge tables with millions rec's, ORDER and ORDER_DETAILS

```
    ORDER
    id NUMBER;
    desc VARCHAR;
    code VARCHAR;
    total_amount NUMBER;

    ORDER_DETAILS    
    id NUMBER;
    desc VARCHAR;
    code VARCHAR;
    amount NUMBER;

    ORDER table contains 'total amount' per id, desc
    ORDER 
    ID DESC CODE, TOTAL_AMOUNT
    1  tl1  OTL1  20
    2  tl2  OTL8  50
```

ORDER_DETAILS contains semi-total (amount) per order (id&desc)

```
ORDER_DETAILS 
    ID DESC CODE, AMOUNT
    1  tl1  NULL  10
    1  tl1  NULL  10
    2  tl2  NULL  10
    2  tl2  NULL  10
    2  tl2  NULL  20
    2  tl2  NULL  10
```

I need to update order_detail.code using the algorithm:

```
 IF SUM(AMOUNT) = TOTAL_AMOUNT -per id & desc
 THEN UPDATE SET order_detail.code=ORDER.CODE
```

So, the results should be:

```
ORDER_DETAILS 
 ID DESC CODE, AMOUNT
 1  tl1  OTL1  10
 1  tl1  OTL1  10
 2  tl2  OTL8  10
 2  tl2  OTL8  10
 2  tl2  OTL8  20
 2  tl2  OTL8  10
```

I tried the following, but it never ends:

```
    UPDATE ORDER_DETAIL A SET A.CODE = (SELECT TEMP1.CODE
                                         FROM                        
                                        ( SELECT 
                                           ID, 
                                           CODE,
                                           DESC,
                                           TOTAL_AMOUNT,
                                           SUM (AMOUNT) SUMAMNT
                                          FROM ORDER A, ORDER_DETAIL B
                                          WHERE A.ID  = B.ID
                                          AND   A.DESC  = B.DESC    
                                          AND   B.AMOUNT<>0
                                          AND   B.CODE IS NULL 
                                          GROUP BY AMOUNT ,ID, CODE, DESC, TOTAL_AMOUNT 
                                          HAVING SUM (AMOUNT) = A.TOTAL_AMOUNT) TEMP1
                                          WHERE A.ID=TEMP1.ID
                                          AND   A.DESC=TEMP1.DESC
                                        );
```

How can I achieve the desired result? If possible using a single sql statement?
Any help is appreciated and thanking you in advance

Hi Tejash,
Thank you for your answer
Please check below plan,, cost is huge,, it perform full scan on both tables –twice @ORDER_DETAILS

Plan

```
MERGE STATEMENT  CHOOSE
Cost: 2.894.308                                     
    13 MERGE ORDER_DETAILS                              
        12 VIEW                             
            11 HASH JOIN  Cost: 2.894.308  Bytes: 246,708  Cardinality: 1,068                       
                8 VIEW  Cost: 2.375.331  Bytes: 115,344  Cardinality: 1,068                     
                    7 FILTER                
                        6 SORT GROUP BY  Cost: 2.375.331  Bytes: 76,896  Cardinality: 1,068             
                            5 HASH JOIN  Cost: 2.367.824  Bytes: 3.834.697.392  Cardinality: 53.259.686         
                                2 PARTITION RANGE ALL  Cost: 517,16  Bytes: 1.757.569.638  Cardinality: 53.259.686  
                                    1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE ORDER_DETAILS Cost: 517,16  Bytes: 1.757.569.638  Cardinality: 53.259.686  
                                4 PARTITION RANGE ALL  Cost: 1.512.742  Bytes: 3.576.967.836  Cardinality: 91.717.124  
                                    3 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE ORDER Cost: 1.512.742  Bytes: 3.576.967.836  Cardinality: 91.717.124  
                10 PARTITION RANGE ALL  Cost: 518,328  Bytes: 6.550.941.378  Cardinality: 53.259.686    
                    9 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE ORDER_DETAILS Cost: 518,328  Bytes: 6.550.941.378  Cardinality: 53.259.686
```

Comment: Hi community, any further suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Im only familiar with msSQL, but I think the following is standard SQL and apply to most DBs.

```
Begin tran
 Update t 
      Set t.code = t.hdr
  From(
     Select d.code, o.code as her
       From order_detail d
        Join order o on o.id = d.id) t
Commit tran
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MERGE` statement as follows (It will be faster than your `UPDATE` statement):

```
MERGE INTO ORDER_DETAILS TRG 
USING 
(
   SELECT
       O.ID, O.DESC, O.CODE, 
       SUM(OD.AMOUNT),
       O.TOTAL_AMOUNT
   FROM
       ORDER_DETAILS OD
       JOIN "ORDER" O ON O.ID = OD.ID AND O.DESC = OD.DESC
   GROUP BY O.ID, O.DESC, O.CODE, O.TOTAL_AMOUNT
   HAVING O.TOTAL_AMOUNT = SUM(OD.AMOUNT)
)
SRC ON ( SRC.ID = TRG.ID AND SRC.DESC = TRG.DESC )
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET TRG.CODE = SRC.CODE;
```

Cheers!!